# wp_nav_menu inserts <ul>, no way of setting class or avoiding found

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This seems to be a general issue, and tried a lot of different solutions, but seems like its either broken or I am missing something.

The function wp_nav_menu insists on inserting a  without any classes or anything, and it kind of messes up the menu quite badly (using bootstrap on the theme building it with underscore). Is there any way to either telling it just not to add  or force it to add class.

Code:

```
          <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'    =>  'primary',
                    'container'         =>  'nav',
                    'container_class'   =>  'navbar-collapse collapse',
                    'menu_class'        =>  'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
                    )
                );
            ?>
```

Also tried:

```
> <?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => '',
> 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'show_home'
> => '1')); ?>
```

and

```
 <?php
wp_nav_menu(
 array(
'menu_class'=>"nav navbar-nav navbar-right",
'menu_id'=>"",
 'container'=>"",
 'theme_location'=>"primary-menu",
 )
 );
```

And in all cases, it outputs a  without any class applied

```
        <div class="navbar">
            <nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="http://localhost:18888/about/">About</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-18"><a href="http://localhost:18888/blog/">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-8 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost:18888/">Intro</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-14"><a href="http://localhost:18888/join/">Join</a></li>
            </ul></nav>


        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have managed to replicate your issue with your code, however, when I changed the theme_location to a location I had created within my functions.php, the ID was removed and the classes were added.

Can I ask if you have set up the register_nav_menus function within functions.php?

Comment: Would be happy to, could I be horrible and ask how that is done, believe underscores already does it for me with the line   register_nav_menus( array(
   'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'tentogive' ),
  ) ); which is called through the tentogive_setup add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'tentogive_setup' );

Comment: From your code, your theme location is 'menu-1'. If you change this within your wp_nav_menu call, hopefully this will now work.

Comment: That worked a charm, thank you very much

Comment: No problem, I have added this as an answer if you can accept it, that would be great. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above,*'menu-1'* is classed as your `theme_location`. If you update this within your `wp_nav_menu` call, this will now work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code, which allow you to add the classes to **ul**, and also allow you to remove the **nav** tag.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'    => 'primary','menu_id'=> 'main-menu','container'=>false,'menu_class'=>'main-navigation')); ?>
```

HTML Output :

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="main-navigation">
    <li id="menu-item-1772" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1772">
        <a href="#">Test a</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Did not work, seems like it changes the div around it, but still throws in the empty UL

Comment: can you please paste the actual output with that blank ul for my reference

Comment: It liturally just outputs <ul><li ...      .... </li></ul>, but seems like it works if I call a registered menu array for whatever reason, not the most intuitive solution, but if it works I am happy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it 2 steps as follow.

> 1st step, we have to register navigation menu in the file functions.php, for
>   example code.

```
function pluto_theme_setup()
{
    add_theme_support('menus');
    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Header Navigation');
}

add_action('init', 'pluto_theme_setup');
```

> 2nd step, we can call the primary with wp_nav_menu in the file
>   header.php, for example code.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PLUTO</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content-right">
                <?php wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                        'container' => false,
                        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'))
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```